# JQuery Swiper slide height

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, swiper.js

I am using [JQuery Swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WFHCmX2MHo0).  I essentially have a section where I set the height to the viewport height.

```
#portfolio {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Within this section, I have a left side and a right side, which I set to 100%

```
#portfolio-left {
    background: #6bbea5 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#portfolio-right {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

`#portfolio-left` will just hold a little text, while `#portfolio-right` will hold my slider.

So I have added my slider container, and the contents I want added to the slider.  I then set it up

```
$(function() {

     var swiperH = new Swiper('.swiper-container-h', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination-h',
        paginationClickable: true
    });
    var swiperV = new Swiper('.swiper-container-v', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination-v',
        paginationClickable: true,
        direction: 'vertical',
        freeMode: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        grabCursor: true
    });
});
```

It will eventually be bi-directional hence the reason I have vertical and horizontal.  I have added two slides vertically to demonstrate my issue.  Essentially, the first slide has a lot of content, and it is not being given a dynamic height.  I believe this has something to do with giving it 100% height on the portfolio-right, but not too sure.  I have set up a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9fup6aq/2/) to demonstrate.

How can I get the slides to have an auto height, whilst at the same time having the whole section 100vh?

This is an example of what I am after
[image: Example]

Many thanks

Comment: The `autoHeight` option is for the slider container itself, not the individual slides. It could be easier to make the slider work how you want it, show us that in a fiddle, then we can figure out how to make it stretch to the full height of the viewport.

Comment: Hi, I added a JSFiddle to the original post.  What I am trying to do is make each individual slide have an automatic height so it can contain all of its content

Comment: I know the answer, and have got it working for the first slide. Though the structure of each slide is a bit complex, so I'm having trouble fixing the fiddle completely. When you use `height:100%`, it takes the height of the parent element. But if no height is set on the parent element, it won't find a height to use. You need to add `height:100%` all the way up the chain until the wrapper, so that the wrapper's height can filter back down. Have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L9fup6aq/3/) and let me know if it's heading in the right direction.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: can you show what kind of output you want

Comment: It's difficult to show.  I have several vertical slides.  I need these slides to have a height which is not fixed, but fits to the content.  So if a slide has content that takes up 300px height, then the slide should be 300px.  If the next slide needs 1200px, then this slide should be 1200px

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like JSFiddle is might be having a little trouble adapting to Swiper. But here is a [fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4m84z8qm/2/). However, It works perfectly on XAMPP server and I moved it to a [live site](http://imarketingguy.com/code-testing/swiper.html) as well.

```
  $(function() {
     var swiperH = new Swiper('.swiper-container-h', {
     pagination: '.swiper-pagination-h',
     paginationClickable: true,
     });

     var swiperV = new Swiper('.swiper-container-v', {
     pagination: '.swiper-pagination-v',
     paginationClickable: true,
     direction: 'vertical',
     freeMode: true,
     autoHeight: true,
     grabCursor: true,
     slidesPerView: 'auto'        
  });
});
```

Notice the addition of "slidesPerView: 'auto' "

Most recent version of Swiper

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/css/swiper.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/js/swiper.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not quite what I am after, I have added an image to the OP to try and explain further.  So the left section is 100vh.  The right section is also 100vh.  However, within the right section, I have a slider.  This slider container should be 100%, however the slides within it should have an auto height to fit its content.  If you look at the example on the sliders page, I am using the nested example.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, many thanks for the reply.  I have tried replicating what you have done here http://kingandtuke.com/emm/test.html but seem to be having issues.  It does not seem to work with the auto height.  Do you notice anything I seem to be doing differently?  Thanks

Comment: @kate_hudson I don't know if I need to use the "@person" to notify them in the comments. But I think I have it figured out. Update your cdn links to the most current version. I added the links to my answer.

Comment: didn't know about the name tagging :-) Thank you very much for all your help, updating the libraries worked a treat.  Many thanks.  For some reason it automatically gave out the bounty, will try and get it changed :-)

Comment: @kate_hudson bounty is no big deal. Happy to help. I learned a little bit about something I've never seen before 

Answer (score 2):

Man, I've refactored the CSS, considering the HTML hierarchy

See if this is what you need: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9fup6aq/4/)

```js
$(function() {
     var swiperH = new Swiper('.swiper-container-h', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination-h',
        paginationClickable: true
    });
    var swiperV = new Swiper('.swiper-container-v', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination-v',
        paginationClickable: true,
        direction: 'vertical',
        freeMode: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        grabCursor: true
    });
});
```

```css
#portfolio {
  height: 100vh;
}

#portfolio-left {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #6bbea5 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

#portfolio-right {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  color: #000;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

.swiper-slide {
  display: table;
}

.goldBG {
  background: #fabc2f;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.0.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.0.0/js/swiper.jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="portfolio">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-5" id="portfolio-left">
        <div id="portfolio-title">
            <h2>Work</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-7" id="portfolio-right">
        <div class="swiper-container swiper-container-h">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="swiper-container swiper-container-v">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            <div class="swiper-slide goldBG">
                                <div class="row addMargin">
                                    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 vertical-center inner">
                                        <div class="content-holder-l">
                                            <p>French</p>
                                            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row addMargin">
                                    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 vertical-center inner">
                                        <div class="content-holder-l">
                                            <p>French</p>
                                            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row addMargin">
                                    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 vertical-center inner">
                                        <div class="content-holder-l">
                                            <p>French</p>
                                            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row addMargin">
                                    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 vertical-center inner">
                                        <div class="content-holder-l">
                                            <p>French</p>
                                            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix">
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                duyfghisdgfdshfsdygfuygdsufygsdgyudgsyfugsdyugf
                                <br> sdf
                                <br> sdfsdfsdfsd
                                <br> fsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-v"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-h"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The fiddle you have shown seems to have an infinite scroll, and the slides do not fit the content.  I have added an image to the OP to try and demonstrate.  If you look at the examples on the sliders homepage I am using a nested slider.  Thanks